# Capturing Image via Android Camera and comparing it with images in MySQL database using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

Good day, StackOverflow! I am a new member here and I need your help on this matter.

I have an Android project and I am having trouble solving this problem.

Basically, what I want to do is this: I am going to capture an image of a diseased plant using the Android Camera intent. Then the app will pass the bitmap image onto a function where it will be preprocessed (specifically, the image will be resized), and the resized bitmap will then be sent to a function where the bitmap image will then be converted to a Mat object and sent to an AsyncTask-triggered function (with the Mat object of the bitmap image as the parameter).

```
public void processImage(final Bitmap bmp)
{
    class ProcessImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> //This AsyncTask triggers the function matchAndCompare().
    {   
        Mat srcImage = new Mat(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4, new Scalar(4));
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            plsWait = ProgressDialog.show(CameraView.this, "Dur-Yan!", "Please wait. Processing image. " +
                    "Patience is appreciated since it will definitely pass.");
        }           
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps)
        {
            matchAndCompare(srcImage); //The function where the main processing and matching takes place.
            return null;                
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);                
            plsWait.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Utils.matToBitmap(srcImage, bmp);
                    imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    forUpload(srcImage, bmp);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    ProcessImage process = new ProcessImage();
    process.execute(bmp);       
}
```

And this is the function where the main image processing takes place. This function will detect the keypoints and compute the descriptors for the source image. Then it will go over (query) the entries in the database, retrieve each bitmap image, convert each of them to Mat objects, detect keypoints, compute descriptors, then store the descriptors for each of the images.

```
public void matchAndCompare (Mat source)
{
    //Initialize minimum and maximum threshold
    int MIN_MATCH_THRESHOLD = 10;
    int MAX_MATCH_THRESHOLD = 250;

    //Initialize DescriptorMatcher
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_SL2);

    //Initialize MatOfDMatch
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    MatOfDMatch goodMatches = new MatOfDMatch();

    //Initialize good matches list
    LinkedList<DMatch> listOfGoodMatches = new LinkedList<>();

    //Initialize object lists
    LinkedList<Point> refObjectList = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Point> srcObjectList = new LinkedList<>();

    Log.e(TAG, "Source image channels: " + source.channels());
    //Pre-process source image and compute for keypoints
    Imgproc.cvtColor(source, source, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
    MatOfKeyPoint srcKeyPoints = createDetector(source);
    Mat srcDescriptors = extractDescription(srcKeyPoints, source);
    MatOfPoint2f srcPoint2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
    //Features2d.drawKeypoints(source, srcKeyPoints, source);

    //Retrieve images from online database, pre-process and compute for keypoints
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    int i = 0;              
    if (connected == true)
    {
        try 
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_retrieve_images);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e(TAG, "Connection successful");
            //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), “pass”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in HTTP connection" + e.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //convert response to string
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), “Input Reading pass”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result" + e.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //parse json data
        ArrayList<Images> imgs = new ArrayList<Images>();               
        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                // Obtain images from MySQL database, stream them as Bitmap, and convert them to Mat.
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Images images = new Images();
                images.setImage_Name(json_data.getString("image_name"));
                imgs.add(images);                           
                String ImgLoc = "http://duryan-itp.host56.com/uploads/" + images.getImage_Name();

                //Bitmap referenceImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL(ImgLoc).openStream());
                Mat refImage = new Mat(ImageFromURL(ImgLoc).getWidth(), ImageFromURL(ImgLoc).getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4, new Scalar(4));
                Log.i(TAG, "Successfully converted " + ImgLoc + " to Mat()");

                //Pre-process reference image and compute for keypoints
                Log.e(TAG, "Reference image channels: " + refImage.channels());
                Imgproc.cvtColor(refImage, refImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
                MatOfKeyPoint refKeyPoints = createDetector(refImage);
                Mat refDescriptors = extractDescription(refKeyPoints, refImage);
                MatOfPoint2f refPoint2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
                //Features2d.drawKeypoints(refImage, refKeyPoints, refImage);

                // Apply brute-force matching
                Log.i(TAG, "Image matching in progress...\n" + "Matching image with template: " + images.getImage_Name());
                Log.e(TAG, srcDescriptors.toString());
                Log.e(TAG, refDescriptors.toString());
                if (srcDescriptors.empty())
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Source descriptor array is empty!");
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                else if (refDescriptors.empty())
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Reference descriptor array is empty!");
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                else if (srcDescriptors.empty() && refDescriptors.empty())
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Both descriptor arrays are empty!");
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    matcher.match(srcDescriptors, refDescriptors, matches);

                    //Initialize match list
                    double max_dist = 0;
                    double min_dist = 100;
                    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();

                    for (int r = 0; r < refDescriptors.rows(); r++)
                    {
                        Double distance = (double) matchesList.get(r).distance;
                        if (distance < min_dist)
                        {
                            min_dist = distance;
                        }
                        if (distance > max_dist)
                        {
                            max_dist = distance;
                        }
                    }

                    for (int s = 0; s < refDescriptors.rows(); s++)
                    {
                        if (matchesList.get(i).distance < 3 * min_dist)
                        {
                            listOfGoodMatches.add(matchesList.get(s));
                        }
                    }

                    goodMatches.fromList(listOfGoodMatches);

                    List<KeyPoint> refObjectListKeypoints = refKeyPoints.toList();
                    List<KeyPoint> srcObjectListKeypoints = srcKeyPoints.toList();

                    for (int t = 0; t < listOfGoodMatches.size(); t++) 
                    {
                        refObjectList.addLast(refObjectListKeypoints.get(listOfGoodMatches.get(t).queryIdx).pt);
                        srcObjectList.addLast(srcObjectListKeypoints.get(listOfGoodMatches.get(t).trainIdx).pt);
                    }

                    refPoint2f.fromList(refObjectList);
                    srcPoint2f.fromList(srcObjectList);

                    String ifMatch;
                    if(listOfGoodMatches.size() > MIN_MATCH_THRESHOLD && listOfGoodMatches.size() < MAX_MATCH_THRESHOLD)
                    {
                        ifMatch = "Match found! Determining severity...";
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        ifMatch = "No match found!";
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, ifMatch);
                }
                plsWait.dismiss();                      
                finish();                   
            }                       
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "JSON error occurred!");
            finish();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException error occurred!");
            finish();
        }
        catch (CvException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "An error has occurred during image processing!");
            finish();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(CameraView.this, "Image retrieval failed. Check your Internet connection!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Image retrieval failed. Check your Internet connection!");                      
            }
        });
        finish();
    }
}
public MatOfKeyPoint createDetector (Mat matrix)
{
    FeatureDetector detect = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detect.detect(matrix, keypoints);
    return keypoints;
}

public Mat extractDescription (MatOfKeyPoint keypoint, Mat matrix)
{
    DescriptorExtractor descExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
    Mat descriptors = new Mat();
    descExtractor.compute(matrix, keypoint, descriptors);
    return descriptors;
}
```

Now the main problem is that when I did an error checking on the descriptors of both the source and reference Mat objects, they both returned empty! Also, the app crashes with the following errors (from LogCat):

```
06-02 20:08:02.319: E/Dur-Yan!(3891): Source image channels: 4
06-02 20:08:02.340: E/GED(3891): Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
06-02 20:08:06.014: E/Dur-Yan!(3891): Connection successful
06-02 20:08:15.721: E/Dur-Yan!(3891): Reference image channels: 4
06-02 20:08:16.381: E/Dur-Yan!(3891): Mat [ 0*0*CV_8UC1, isCont=false, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0xffffffffaf848548, dataAddr=0x0 ]
06-02 20:08:16.381: E/Dur-Yan!(3891): Mat [ 0*0*CV_8UC1, isCont=false, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0xffffffffaf848628, dataAddr=0x0 ]
06-02 20:08:16.382: E/Dur-Yan!(3891): Source descriptor array is empty!
06-02 20:08:16.411: E/cv::error()(3891): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 97
06-02 20:08:16.415: E/org.opencv.android.Utils(3891): nMatToBitmap catched cv::Exception: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891): Process: com.yurinymous.android.duryan, PID: 3891
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891): CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891): ]
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at org.opencv.android.Utils.nMatToBitmap2(Native Method)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(Utils.java:123)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(Utils.java:132)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.yurinymous.android.duryan.CameraView$1ProcessImage$1.run(CameraView.java:613)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5384)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.yurinymous.android.duryan.CameraView$1ProcessImage.onPostExecute(CameraView.java:609)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.yurinymous.android.duryan.CameraView$1ProcessImage.onPostExecute(CameraView.java:1)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
06-02 20:08:16.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

I want to know what I'm doing wrong here. I hope you guys can help me about this. I am new to OpenCV, by the way, so whatever insights you may have will greatly aid me in the completion of this project.

P.S.: This Android project is my final requirement before I will graduate. Thank you and more power!

Comment: what has this got to do with mysql?

Comment: @e4c5 The reference images are stored in an online MySQL database.

Comment: yes but that has nothing to do with this problem. Programming is like eating an elephant. If your problem is with open CV. First learn how to compare two statically stored images. Then replace one with one grabbed from the camera. Then replace the other with one retrieved from the web. Even then your android app absolutely does not need to know that mysql is used in the server.

Comment: I see, @e4c5. Now, all I need to know is what am I really doing wrong here. :)